# R: How to parse a string of dates in dataframe, split it, and return the date closest to today?

Tags: r

I really apologize for the question but I am new to R. I have a dataframe with 2 columns. The first column contains names and the second one a string of dates in text format ("YYYYMMDD"). I am trying to split the string in the second column and get the closest day to today for every row in the dataframe. Below is a sample of the dataframe:

```
Column 1  Column2 
Name 1    20190607,20200901,20211203           
Name 2  20190607,20200901,20211203
```

The end result should look like the sample dataframe but with a column to the right showing the dates closest to today. In this example it would be 20211203. Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `separate_rows` to split the 'Column2' at the `,`, into new rows, then convert the 'Column2' to `Date` class (`ymd` from `lubridate`) and `slice` the rows where the difference from `today` is the minimum (after grouping by 'Column1')

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df2 <- df1 %>%
    separate_rows(Column2, sep=",\\s*") %>%
    mutate(Column2 = ymd(Column2)) %>%
    group_by(Column1) %>%
    slice(which.min(abs(Column2 - today()))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
df2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Column1 Column2   
  <chr>   <date>    
1 Name 1  2021-12-03
2 Name 2  2021-12-03
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Column1 = c("Name 1", "Name 2"), Column2 = c("20190607,20200901,20211203", 
"20190607,20200901,20211203")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to just keep the dataframe with the closest to today dates? When I try to view the dataframe after your code, it still shows the dataframe with the long string of dates

Comment: @matteo123 Probably you are checking the original data `df1`.  The code i showed didn't get assigned to an object.  If you want to update original object (which I don't reocmmend) use `df1 <- df1 %>% separate_rows(...` or assign it to new object `df2 <- df1 %>% ...` and then check `df2`

Answer (score 1):

```r
DF = read.csv(text = "'Name 1';'20190607,20200901,20211203'
'Name 2';'20190607,20200901,20211203'", sep=";", header=F, quote="'")

DF
     V1                          V2
1 Name 1 20190607,20200901,20211203 
2 Name 2  20190607,20200901,20211203

strsplit(DF[[2]], ',') |>
lapply(\(x) as.Date(x,format="%Y%m%d")) |> 
lapply(max) # `max` gets you the closest date to today since a date class is internally represented in integer using origin 1970 (i.e. 0).
[[1]]
[1] "2021-12-03"

[[2]]
[1] "2021-12-03"
```

You can assign the result to the data.frame as a new column.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on comma, take difference of current date with all other dates, return the date with minimum difference for each row.

Here is a base R option  -

```
df$Column3 <- as.Date(sapply(strsplit(df$Column2, ','), function(x) {
  x <- as.Date(x, '%Y%m%d')
  x[which.min(abs(x - Sys.Date()))]
}), origin = '1970-01-01')
df

#  Column1                    Column2    Column3
#1  Name 1 20190607,20200901,20211203 2021-12-03
#2  Name 2 20190607,20200901,20211203 2021-12-03
```